# Sync over Async - threads usage clarification

Tags: c#, async-await

I saw David fowler's and Demian at the [NDC](https://youtu.be/J-xqz_ZM9Wg?t=1024) and they've talked about scaling.

At the beginning of the presentation they've asked the audience: " How many threads are involved here in this code : "

```
void Main()
{
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
}
```

Then @jonskeet said: "at least 2".

The first thread is the main thread and I can assume that the second thread is the one used by Delay ( timer ), which at the end grabs another thread from the thread pool ( I hope I'm right on this one). There is no await here. So I don't think there is a state machine here.

**Question**

But why is there another option for another thread ? ( he said at least 2). Can someone please clarify what's the thread usage in this simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why is there another option for another thread ?

Speculation, but: we know that there is not an OS level timer per delay; instead, as an implementation detail there is a linked-list (ordered by timeout) of pending timers, and only the first node is actually scheduled to the OS.

Now imagine the OS-level timeout triggers; it needs to do multiple things:

- activate the callbacks of *all* items with the same timeout value
- schedule an OS timeout for the next item with a later timeout
- book-keeping

The infrastructure code probably doesn't want one slowly written callback to delay all the others, so it almost certainly hands the callback activation to the thread-pool, rather than invoking the callback synchronously. It is *possible*, but not guaranteed, that the book-keeping etc will happen fast enough that the same worker thread picks up the callbacks from the pool; a more likely option is that an unrelated thread-pool thread deals with that.

So; we have

- your primary thread
- the thread handling the OS timeout and scheduling callbacks onto the thread-pool
- the thread-pool thread picking up the callback

Answer (score 1):

For a definitive answer, only Jon can answer the question, since he's the one who uttered the phrase you're asking about. Fortunately, in this case there's a real possibility he might.

That said, I would say the "at least" is mainly acknowledgement that there any number of other sources of other threads, never mind it depends on what the original question actually meant by *"involved here"*. For example, simply accessing the thread pool could result in some minimum of threads being created immediately; they may not be used, but they could still be there.

Furthermore, .NET has for some time had a multithreaded garbage collector. So the mere fact you're dealing with a .NET program means there could be that GC thread involved. For that matter, there could also be the finalizer thread.

All *that* said, I would say that generally, you could expect there to just be the two threads. The thread pool by default will create threads immediately up to some maximum number, but only as needed. And in the given code example, there's not going to be any demand for garbage collection. When I run the example you show in a default .NET 5 project, I get just the two threads you'd expect:

[image]